# Complete a task when an event fires

Tags: c#, task, continuations

This should be simple but I just can't bring it into focus.

In this method

```
public static async Task<string> UnloadAsync(Assembly assy, bool silentFail = false)
{
  if (AssyLoadContext.__alcd.ContainsKey(assy))
  {
    var assemblyName = __namd.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == assy).First().Key;
    __alcd[assy].Unloading += alc => //signal the task to complete and return assemblyName
    __namd.Remove(assemblyName);
    __alcd[assy].Unload();
    __alcd.Remove(assy);
    Debug.WriteLine($"Unloaded assembly '{assy.GetName().Name}'");
  }
  if (silentFail) 
  {
    return null;
  }
  else
  {
    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Assembly '{assy.GetName().Name}' cannot be unloaded. Did you load it using AssyLoadContext.LoadWithPrivateContext(string assyPath)?");
  }
}
```

the `AssemblyLoadContext.Unload()` operation is actually asynchronous, but isn't awaitable. Once there are no more strong GC references etc the operation completes, the assembly unloads and the Unloading event fires.

The return value is in `assemblyName` which I want to provide to a continuation.

All the documentation I can find blathers about the need for `await` because that's where the yield happens, but I can't write it that way. How do you do this without `await`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for a [`TaskCompletionSource<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=net-5.0):

```
public static Task<string> UnloadAsync(Assembly assy, bool silentFail = false)
{
  if (AssyLoadContext.__alcd.ContainsKey(assy))
  {
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    var assemblyName = __namd.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == assy).First().Key;
    __alcd[assy].Unloading += alc => tcs.SetResult(assemblyName);
    __namd.Remove(assemblyName);
    __alcd[assy].Unload();
    __alcd.Remove(assy);
    Debug.WriteLine($"Unloaded assembly '{assy.GetName().Name}'");
    return tcs.Task;
  }
  if (silentFail)
  {
    return Task.FromResult<string>(null);
  }

  throw new InvalidOperationException($"Assembly '{assy.GetName().Name}' cannot be unloaded. Did you load it using AssyLoadContext.LoadWithPrivateContext(string assyPath)?");
  }
}
```

Note that if this throws an `InvalidOperationException`, it gets thrown when `UnloadAsync` is called, rather than being wrapped in the returned `Task` (which is what would happen if your method was `async`). If you want to change this, you can either use the TaskCompletionSource:

```
public static Task<string> UnloadAsync(Assembly assy, bool silentFail = false)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
  if (AssyLoadContext.__alcd.ContainsKey(assy))
  {
    var assemblyName = __namd.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == assy).First().Key;
    __alcd[assy].Unloading += alc => tcs.SetResult(assemblyName);
    __namd.Remove(assemblyName);
    __alcd[assy].Unload();
    __alcd.Remove(assy);
    Debug.WriteLine($"Unloaded assembly '{assy.GetName().Name}'");
  }
  else if (silentFail)
  {
    tcs.SetResult(null);
  }
  else
  {
    tcs.SetException(new InvalidOperationException($"Assembly '{assy.GetName().Name}' cannot be unloaded. Did you load it using AssyLoadContext.LoadWithPrivateContext(string assyPath)?"));
  }
  
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

Or use an `async` method:

```
public static async Task<string> UnloadAsync(Assembly assy, bool silentFail = false)
{
  if (AssyLoadContext.__alcd.ContainsKey(assy))
  {
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    var assemblyName = __namd.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == assy).First().Key;
    __alcd[assy].Unloading += alc => tcs.SetResult(assemblyName);
    __namd.Remove(assemblyName);
    __alcd[assy].Unload();
    __alcd.Remove(assy);
    Debug.WriteLine($"Unloaded assembly '{assy.GetName().Name}'");
    return await tcs.Task;
  }
  if (silentFail)
  {
    return null;
  }

  throw new InvalidOperationException($"Assembly '{assy.GetName().Name}' cannot be unloaded. Did you load it using AssyLoadContext.LoadWithPrivateContext(string assyPath)?");
}
```

Comment: Great answer. FWIW: I see no benefit to the final code snippet. The first code snippet can be used in any `async` context. The method doesn't need to be `async` itself; returning a `Task` is sufficient. The only reason to make a method `async` is if there is some benefit to using `await` within it. Here, there is no benefit; the only use is `return await tcs.Task;`. The caller is going to do that `await` anyway.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve it's potentially clearer imo. It maps much more closely to the OP's code. If there are other exceptions, they'll get handled better in the `async` version also

Comment: Thanks. I forgot OP had an async method. Explain how `async` affects exceptions - I thought they would propagate the same either way, assuming a`Task` is returned, and that the ONLY `await` is `return await tcs.Task`. Replacing with `return tcs.Task`, I'm assuming caller still does `await UnloadAsync(...);`

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve One method is marked async, one is not. In an async method, any exceptions thrown are wrapped up inside the Task which is returned. In a non-async method, ant exceptions are thrown straight to the caller. That matters if the caller stores the resulting Task in a local/field before awaiting it. See eg the classic https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html